# how to redirect any api request from http to https in django?

Tags: django, api, ssl, nginx, https

after migrating my Django web app from HTTP to https, when I type

for example `r= requests.get('http://xxxx.com')`

it gives me this error :

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=my_host_name,port:443)  Max retries exceeded with url:http://xxxx.com (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),))
```

but I made the nginx config for the redirection for example when I put any HTTP address on my browser it redirects me to the correct https address.

I would like to do the same thing on the API request.

I don't like to change my requests addresses on my backend code I just want to redirect the HTTP requests to https if it is possible?

my nginx config :

```
http {

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  proxy_cache_path /path/cache keys_zone=cache:10m levels=1:2 inactive=600s 
  max_size=100m;
  default_type application/octet-stream;


    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

  access_log /path/access.log;
  error_log /Path/error.log error;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  upstream app_servers {

    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  server {

    listen 443  ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /PATH/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /PATH/certificate.key;
    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    server_name  my_host_name;
    access_log /path/nginx-access.log compression;
    location /static/  {
       alias /path/static/;

 }

location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        allow all;
        deny all;
}

    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_read_timeout 1200;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
 }
 server {
   listen 9999 ;
   server_name my_host_name ;
   return 307 https://my_domain.com$request_uri;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you should include you Nginx configuration before we can help you out in a meaningful way.

Comment: here it is my Nginx config @NicoGriffioen

Answer (score 0):

The error kind of puzzles me, but in you Nginx config file, I see that you're not listening on the default HTTP port. You should add a server block that listens on the HTTP (80) port, and redirect to https (443) from there.

Add this block inside your http:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  my_host_name;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: thanks @NicoGriffioen but sadly i tried to add this block of code but it doesn't work.
also in my case, my default port is 9999 and i tried to change 80 by 9999 also doesn't work. :/

Comment: What do you mean your default port is 9999?

Comment: my port before the migration to SSL

Comment: http://xxxx.com will default to port 80, so unless you specify port 9999 in your request url, it's not going to work anyway. I'm not sure why it's not working after you changed the Nginx config.

Comment: i didn't understand why on the browser it works and with rest-API didn't!
it gives me this error requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=my_host_name,port:443)  Max retries exceeded with url:http://xxxx.com (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),))